# jQuery: Initial Load of Page does not find Element, but when resize happens, element is found.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to add and remove a class depending on if `.woocommerce-mini-cart` is shorter than it's parent element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function maybeAdjustCartClass() {
    let cartWrapper         = $( '.woocommmerce-mini-cart-wrapper' );
    let cartHeight          = $( '.woocommerce-mini-cart' ).height();
    let cartLength          = $( '.woocommerce-mini-cart' ).length;
    let cartContainerHeight = $( '.widget_shopping_cart_content' ).height();

    if ( cartLength < 1 || cartHeight < cartContainerHeight ) {
        cartWrapper.addClass( 'add-height' );
    } else {
        cartWrapper.removeClass( 'add-height' );
    }
  }

  maybeAdjustCartClass();

  $( window ).on( 'resize', function() {
     maybeAdjustCartClass();
  } );
});
```

On page load, the `cartHeight` is `null` and `cartLength` is `0`. As soon as I do any resizing of any sort, everything works as expected. Cart Length says 1 and `.woocommerce-mini-cart` matches the height that inspector says it as and the class gets added and removed to the element. It only doesn't work on page load. I tried to account for this funkiness by adding `cartLength < 1` operator, as well as trying `cartLength === 0` or `cartHeight === null` all to no avail.

I've even given `.woocommerce-mini-cart` a minimum height of 1px, all to no avail. `.woocommerce-mini-cart` exists on page load and is in the DOM.  I am completely stumped on why this isn't working as expected.

Comment: Suggests to me that class is added *after* page loads. If it's not in the page source it is likely added using javascript

Comment: To fix this, I guess you could just declare that CartLength = 1, and that might work?

Comment: Just curious, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? What does the add-height CSS class do? Is this something that could be accomplished with a pure CSS solution instead?

Comment: @Andrew I tried to do a solo CSS solution, but after hours of trying to accomplish my goal, discovered I need a little JS. This keeps a footer sticky to the bottom of the viewport on an off canvas slide out. Unfortunately their are known bugs in Chrome and Firefox with position: fixed not working well in nested fixed elements and with elements that have transform applied to them. The client's theme's off canvas slide in has both.